# JS: Regular expression to find all function calls in the body of a function

Tags: javascript, regex

I would need a regular expression to return the parameter of a function that begins with APP("name")

So in this example only the second line would match and it would return me the text -name-

```
testing text:

var w = app("name").test
var x = APP("name").test()
var y = SNAPP("name").test()
var z = APPLICATION("name").test()
```

I tried some things out but it's not working: http://www.regexr.com/3a1h2

thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
\bAPP\("([^")]+)
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the string you want from group index 1.

https://regex101.com/r/aQ3zJ3/3

```
> var s = 'var x = APP("name").test()';
undefined
> console.log(/\bAPP\("([^")]+)/.exec(s)[1]);
name
```

Comment: is it possible to just get "name" instead of APP("name"

Comment: @kevinius you have to grab the capture or group

Comment: @kevinius what's your expected output? `name` or `"name"` . I don't want  further editing my answer.

Comment: Maybe i should post a new questions, i think i'm not clear enouph, because i need a list of matches. For instance if i have this string, then i want an array of name, name1, name2 -         var str = 'testing text:\n\nvar w = app("name").test\nvar x = APP("name").test() APP("name2").test() APP("name3").test()\nvar y = SNAPP("name").test()\nvar z = APPLICATION("name").test()';

Comment: an array with name, name1, name2 (without ")

Comment: @kevinius if you use this regex and grab all the captures groups you will get the result you want

Comment: can you show me, do i need to set the /g flag to get all matches in an array?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a word boundary and you must need to escape the `()` brackets so that it would match a literal `(` , `)` symbols.

```
/\bAPP\(([^()]*)\)/
```

`\b` word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. Get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/3a1h5)

```
> var s = 'var x = APP("name").test()';
> console.log(/\bAPP\(([^()]*)\)/.exec(s)[1]);
"name"
```

Comment: posted at the same time, i didn't see yours.

Comment: there's a gap of 3 mins :)

Comment: What if the op wants to match the string `APP()`, and this should return an empty string. But yours won't..

Comment: OP clearly mentions he want `name` that's it.moreover your earlier regex was `^APP\("([^")]+)`

Comment: yep, mine also returns the string `name` . Yep, i agree at first i thought `var` is a variable name that is not included in the input string but after seeing his regex, i realized that it's not. Then i corrected mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\sAPP\(\s*\S.*\)
```

You are picking up SNAPP() as well as APP()

The **\s** checks for a space before the name of the function

Comment: vks's answer is probably a better solution, in case there are no spaces between the equal sign and the function name

Comment: This is selecting everything  APP("name").test() -> i only need "name"

Comment: This might help you with Regex's   The book is free and disclaimer, I wrote it..    http://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks/regularexpressions